# disable [session.use_strict_mode] before starting new generated session

Tags: php, session, initialization

I saw this code on PHP MANUAL and i can't get that =>

why did he disable `session.use_strict_mode` before starting the new generated session then enable it again ?

```
$new_session_id = session_create_id();
$_SESSION['new_session_id'] = $new_session_id;

session_commit();

session_id($new_session_id);
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 0);
session_start();
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);

unset($_SESSION['destroyed']);
unset($_SESSION['new_session_id']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When strict mode is enabled, uninitialized session ID will be discarded. Therefore, applications that use adoptive session
nature may not work. If malicious cookie that prevents new session ID is set, session module will keep trying to generate
new session ID and session will not be usable.

Comment: thnx for answer